# ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit keeps adding the new content into the old one

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have this ASP.NET AJAX toolkit. Each time AJAX is triggered, I get the old data + new data , and it keeps adding and adding ( because I have the += in the code behind) How can I solve this, so that AJAX only shows the updated version, and not keeps adding?

aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
            <ul id="myaspajaxtoolkit" runat="server"></ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employees", cnn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                myaspajaxtoolkit.InnerHtml += "<li>" + dr.GetString(0) + "</li>";
            }
        }
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string html = string.Empty;
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
         html+= "<li>" + dr.GetString(0) + "</li>";
    }
}
myaspajaxtoolkit.InnerHtml = html;
```